# uBoot - Bad gzipped data - Synology DS418J

Tags: kernel, u-boot, synology

I bought broken Synology DS418j where HDD migration destroyed firmware on the flash.With Serial USB Adapter I have access to uBoot console. This uBoot version has just rudimental commands.

To restore "right" firmware I downloaded firmware-package from Synology and unziped the data inside. I need normally two files "zImage" (Kernel) and "rd.bin" (RAMdisk).
https://global.download.synology.com/download/DSM/release/6.2.2/24922/DSM_DS418j_24922.pat?model=DS418j&bays=4&dsm_version=6.2.2&build_number=24922

Here is the content of the ZIP File from Synology:
[image: Content tree]

Here is the ENV print from uBoot:
[image: ENV print]

I can load these images via the command `tftp [addr] [filename]` from my tftp server and boot these files with command `bootm [addr]`. But here is my problem: When I bootm the different images I got error:

```
Realtek> bootm 0x01500000
bootm 0x01500000
## Booting kernel from FIT Image at 01500000 ...
Bad FIT kernel image format!
ERROR: can't get kernel image!
```

Maybe someone can help to load kernel and ramdisk, so I can boot into synology environment and force firmware upgrade to repair this unit.

If you need furhter information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Little Update. I have rewrite the EEPROM with a DUMP consisting of UBOOT + KERNEL + RAMDISK + Vendor + uBoot Config an FIS_directory.

Vendor, uBoot Config and FIS_directory is original.

Problem now is, that I got the following Error:

```
U-Boot 2015.07-g428cfe7-dirty (May 16 2018 - 10:33:51 +0800)

CPU  : Cortex-A53 Quad Core
Board: Realtek QA Board
DRAM:  1 GiB
mapping memory 0x20000000-0x40000000 non-cached
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
rtk_plat_set_fw not port yet, use default configs
Not raw Image, Starting Decompress Image.gz...


Error: Bad gzipped data
Decompress FAIL!!
ERROR do_booti failed!
Realtek>
```

What is now possible to flash right Image.gz?
Is Image.gz the ram-disk?
How can I find out the correct address in flash?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it works again =)
I copied a dump of my working DS418J and programmed it into the bricked DS.

After changing serial number and MAC the unit is working again.